# Adding Custom CsvBulkUploader to ModelAdmin in Silverstripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

after looking at the [documentation](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/integration/csv_import) for the built-in CSV importing, it's still not clear to me how to add a custom CsvBulkUploader to ModelAdmin. I see how you can easily [add the default uploader](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/integration/csv_import#import-through-modeladmin) and how you can [create a custom controller for importing](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/integration/csv_import#import-through-a-custom-controller) but it's not clear to me how you would add this to a ModelAdmin. I've spent the morning looking through Stack Overflow and the SilverStripe community forums, but haven't been able to find anything yet. Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but you may want to look into the import export module (https://github.com/burnbright/silverstripe-importexport). It has a noticeable performance improvement over the default importer and seems a lot more stable to me when importing large data sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

You can add the CSV Bulk Loader to your ModelAdmin by declaring it in `$model_importers`:

```
<?php
class PlayerAdmin extends ModelAdmin {
   private static $managed_models = array(
      'Player'
   );
   private static $model_importers = array(
      'Player' => 'CsvBulkLoader',
   );
   private static $url_segment = 'players';
}
?>
```

And as indicated in the [CSV Import](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/integration/csv_import#import-through-modeladmin) documentation, you can extend the `CsvBulkLoader` class. For example:

```
<?php
class PlayerCsvBulkLoader extends CsvBulkLoader {
   public $columnMap = array(
      'Number' => 'PlayerNumber', 
      ...
   );
   public $duplicateChecks = array(
      'Number' => 'PlayerNumber'
   );
   public $relationCallbacks = array(
      'Team.Title' => array(
         'relationname' => 'Team',
         'callback' => 'getTeamByTitle'
      )
   );
   public static function getTeamByTitle(&$obj, $val, $record) {
      return FootballTeam::get()->filter('Title', $val)->First();
   }
}
?>
```

In the documentation what wasn't made explicit was that you pull in the new extended Bulk Loader by simply adding it to `$model_importers` in your ModelAdmin. So now instead of using `CsvBulkLoader`, you'll be using `PlayerCsvBulkLoader`. The snippet up top would be revised thusly:

```
<?php
class PlayerAdmin extends ModelAdmin {
   private static $managed_models = array(
      'Player'
   );
   private static $model_importers = array(
      'Player' => 'PlayerCsvBulkLoader',
   );
   private static $url_segment = 'players';
}
?>
```

Fairly simple. I had tried this approach early on, but had misspelled the name of the subclass!

**UPDATE:** Just added this to [SilverStripe's documentation](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/integration/csv_import/)

Comment: Nice! `In the documentation what wasn't made explicit was that you pull in the new extended Bulk Loader ` - if you think it would benefit you could submit a pull request to update the docs!

Comment: @RobbieAverill thanks for the suggestion! I just submitted [a pull request](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/pull/6983)